# 18c PDB services are not listed in lsnrctl stat or services

Tags: oracle, listener

The view v$active_services and dba_services and cdb_services are showing the PDB service. But listener is not starting or listing the PDB service.
What would be the issue?

Restarted listener, db but issue was not fixed.
PDBs are dropme2 and servicetest

````
SERVICE_ID NAME NETWORK_NAME CON_NAME
1 SYS$BACKGROUND   CDB$ROOT
2 SYS$USERS   CDB$ROOT
3 host_prim_wfscdb host_prim_wfscdb CDB$ROOT
4 WFSCDB_CFG WFSCDB_CFG CDB$ROOT
6 host_prim_wfscdb_DGB host_prim_wfscdb_DGB CDB$ROOT
12 dropme2 dropme2 DROPME2
14 servicetest servicetest SERVICETEST


oracle@host_prim:~$ lsnrctl stat
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 26-FEB-2020 17:19:20
Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_prim)(PORT=1529)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                26-FEB-2020 16:49:55
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 29 min. 24 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/18.0.0/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/18.0.0/network/log/listener.log
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host_prim)(PORT=1529)))
Services Summary...
Service "WFSCDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "WFSCDB", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "host_prim_wfscdb_DGMGRL" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "WFSCDB", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

oracle@host_prim:~$ lsnrctl services
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 26-FEB-2020 17:22:57
Copyright (c) 1991, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_prim)(PORT=1529)))
Services Summary...
Service "WFSCDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "WFSCDB", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:1 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "host_prim_wfscdb_DGMGRL" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "WFSCDB", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully```
````

Comment: You could try `alter system register` from the PDBs to try to register them with the listener.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
local_listener init.ora parameter was having typo. 
Fixed the typo and missing services are now showing up!!